# Sharing a OneDrive and/or sharepoint folders using "Sharing Link" Vs adding user directly to the Folder permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, folder, sharing

I am planning to move some folders from a user's OneDrive site to a SharePoint document library. to move the files and folders from OneDrive to SharePoint online i will use the "Copy To" and/or "Move To" options. but for the permission i am planning to do the map manually. But on some OneDrive folders i found that they have been shared using sharing link + adding users directly to the folder, here is an example (where 7 users have been added to the folder permission, while one user is added using sharing link):-

[image]

and when i checked the permission for a file inside the above folder, i found the following permission settings, which mentioned that the file inherits the permission from its parent folder (the above permission), and the 7 users are showing inside the file permission settings, as follow:-

[image]

So the file got all the 7 users from the parent folder , but excluding the user who is granted access to the parent folder using sharing link. so my question will the user who has been granted access to the parent folder using sharing link, can access the file? because the child permission setting is confusing, as it is saying that it inherit the permission from the parent folder, but it does not include the user who can access the parent folder suing sharing link.. so not sure how i need to map this to the sharepoint folder? should i grant the user who can access the parent folder using sharing link, access to the file inside the folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i have tested with several folders and meet the same confusion. The file in the folder does not show the user with sharing link. However if you do permission check, the user will show with corresponding permission level granted with the folder. And the user is able to edit files in the folder. Please check with the permission level and do tests with the sharing link user account. It shall not cause any trouble in using.

Comment: thanks for the reply... so you mean the user should be able to edit the files, if the parent folder is shared with him using "sharing link"? i also notified the permission check for the user, that the user will have permission on the file, even if the permission setting screen did not show the user..

Comment: @SharePointTestDev If the permission check shows that the user has permission, then he has. The sharing link shall grant the user permission to edit file in the folder if the file does not have a unique permission. Please always do tests in you end for it is the best way to get more information.